# Google Earth pro integration

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

I have web site where I have customer address. I also have Google Earth Pro installed on my users desktops. I am exploring a possibility to run google Earth Pro and open the directly the location URL.

any one integrated Java Script with Google earth pro? If so plesae let me know how to do the same

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you want Google Earth Pro to launch and have a placemark when someone clicks on a link on your website.

Assuming Google Earth Pro is registered as a helper for the browser, or is registered to handle .kml files in the explorer, when you download a file with that extension or with the Content-Type of 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml', google earth will pick it up and render the kml content.

So the javascript in this case would be used to create the link, or if you find out how to generate a data url, produce that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't integrate JavaScript with Google Earth Pro. At this point, the only KML works in any version of the Google Earth desktop client (in Pro and EC you can import GIS files but they convert to KML). KML is well documented here:

https://developers.google.com/kml/

You can use JavaScript for the Google Earth Plugin using the Earth API:
https://developers.google.com/earth/